# Determining if address is within private CIDR in IPv6?

Tags: ip, ipv6, subnet, netmask

How can we determine if an IPv6 address is within a private CIDR?

On IPv4 it's straightforward, the subnet and the DNS mask are simple enough to understand.

With IPv6 every resource I find looks like the table below - but my own local IPv6 address starts with `fe80`, which doesn't seem to conform to the `fd00` pattern indicated.

Can anyone help me understand private IPv6 ranges and why my own private IPv6 address would seem not to be in that range?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 does not have Private addresses the way IPv4 does. IPv6 used to have Site-Local addresses that were analogous to IPv4 Private addresses, but those were deprecated in favor of ULA (Unique Local Addressing), `fc00::/7`, of which the second half of the addressing, `fd00::/8` is available for local assignment, but requires the next 40 bits to be randomly chosen. IPv4 Private addresses and the (deprecated) IPv6 Site-Local addressing were expected to have the same addresses used in multiple sites, but IPv6 ULA is expected to be unique with little chance for duplicate addresses.

What you are looking at is a Link-Local address (in the `fe80::/10` range). Packets using Link-Local addresses are confined to a single link, unlike IPv6 Global and ULA addresses. You cannot route packets with Link-Local addresses as all links use the same Link-Local network. You can route ULA addresses, but not on the public Internet. Global addresses are globally routable.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, it's very helpful! I remain a bit confused on the core of my question though; is there a reliable way I can determine if a given IPv6 address belongs to a local network? For example, in my use case the idea is to trust links to local addresses, but not to external ones. Sorry if you've already explained this; IPv6 is a bit tough to wrap your head around compared to the simplicity of IPv4.

Comment: Actually, IPv6 is simpler than IPv4. It eliminates complexities such as NAT, and every host can get a Global address, restoring the IP end-to-end paradigm. IPv6 Link-Local addressing (`fe80::/10`) works much the same way as IPv4 Link-Local addressing (`169.254.0.0/16`). It is really for "_addressing on a single link for purposes such as automatic address configuration, neighbor discovery, or when no routers are present._"

Comment: Determining the scope of an IPv6 address is pretty easy: Global addresses are in the `2000::/3` range, ULA addresses are in the `fc00::/7` range, Link-Local addresses are in the `fe80::/10` range, and multicast addresses are in the `ff00::/8` range. It is perfectly fine to use Global addressing, even in a private network, just like you can for IPv4, as long as you have a firewall. You cannot route packets with Link-Local addresses, you can route packets with ULA addresses except not on the Internet, and you can route packets with Global addresses everywhere.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write out those additional details! Can you add some clarification about how the `/10` and `/3` work in IPv6, in terms someone familiar with IPv4 subnet masks could understand? I know it's similar to subnet masking but I can't grasp how exactly it works. What exactly do they signify? I think if your answer touched on that point then it would answer my question.

Comment: It is exactly the same as with IPv4, except where IPv4 addresses are 32 bits, IPv6 addresses are 128 bits. You are probably familiar with something like `192.168.1.0/24`, meaning that the prefix length is 24 bits, and the range is `192.168.1.0` to `192.168.1.255`. For `2000::/3`, the mask length is three bits, so the range is from `2000::` to `3fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` (see [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/78867/8499) about that).